# Regex solution for string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following string:

`bla;bla;<span>bla</span>;bla;bla;hoblala;abla;blala;bla,bla,<span>bla</span>,bla,bla,hoblala,abla,blala,`

I would need to get the "bla" words which are:

- not inside a span
- not inside a word (for example, "hoblala", "abla", "blala"... should not be chosen)

Any help?

EDIT:

regex I tried: `(?!<)(?![a-z])bla`

Comment: use parser instead of regex

Comment: any example or place where I can find examples? Thank you!

Comment: [Creating a DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) you still can use regex parsing though, but it seems less efficient. if you're dealing with complex HTML DOM,

Comment: I'd love it if people would post the code they've tried into their questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(?!<span[^>]*?>)(\b(bla)\b)(?![^<]*?<\/span>)` is what I've come up with.

http://regexr.com/3f67j

It's not a very readable Regex, but it does the job.

I think I'd prefer to break it down into 2 different methods. One to match the whole `bla` word using Regex, and then a second using a HTML parser to remove any that are contained within HTML elements.

Comment: Thank you very much @Dave! This did what I needed :D

Comment: No worries. It will also match `bla-bla` (because word boundary includes `-`), but it shouldn't be too hard to tweak it to exclude it, if that's not what you're after :)

Comment: In my case I will never have bla-bla, so there should be any trouble for me. Thanks again for your answer! You have been very thankful! :D

Answer (score 0):

**This Should Work.**

**REGEXP:**

```
((?:\w+\;)+)(?=<span>)
```

**INPUT:**

```
bla;bla;<span>bla</span>;bla;bla;hoblala;abla;blala;bla,bla,<span>bla</span>,bla,bla,hoblala,abla,blala,
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
bla;bla;
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```js
const regex = /((?:\w+\;)+)(?=<span>)/gm;
const str = `bla;bla;<span>bla</span>;bla;bla;hoblala;abla;blala;bla,bla,<span>bla</span>,bla,bla,hoblala,abla,blala,`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

**See:** https://regex101.com/r/xAzXWh/3